# Proof of "Let $G$ be a group. Then, assuming Zorn's lemma, G has a maximal Abelian subgroup" doubt

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, set-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of this theorem:
Let $G$ be a group. Then, assuming Zorn's lemma, G has a maximal Abelian subgroup.

This is the proof (you don't need to read it all, only the highlighted part is needed, I just put the whole thing because maybe it can be useful for answering the question):

[image]
[image]

The thing I don't understand is, how can the chain $\mathscr{C}$ be in $P$ and the elements of $\mathscr{C}$ be Abelian subgroups of $G$? If the elements of $\mathscr{C}$ are Abelian subgroups of $G$, that means that these elements are in $P$ (since is the set of all Abelian subgroups), so my question would become:
How can the chain $\mathscr{C}$ be in $P$ and the elements of $\mathscr{C}$ be in $P$ as well?

This is how I "visualize" what's going on (you don't need to read this part as well but maybe you can spot the problem of my understanding of this proof):
There is a set $G$ whose elements are proper subgroups. Some of these subgroups are Abelian, and the set of all these Abelian subgroups is the set $P$. Some of these Abelian subgroups are chains and all together they form another set (the book doesn't give any name to this set). We would like to find an upper bound for this set of chains, and a candidate is $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$ (which according to the definition of the book: $\bigcup A=\{q\colon q∈r \text{ for some }r∈A\}$) which is the set of all the elements of the elements of $\mathscr{C}$ (sorry for the wordplay), and two elements of $\mathscr{C}$ are for example $A$ and $B$ whose elements are some $a$ and $b$ respectively.

I don't know if this is correct or I'm misintepreting something. Can you guys help me out please?

Thank you!

Comment: No, $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $P$ means $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain of elements of a poset $P$.  FYI, it is `\mathscr{C}` for a fancy script C.

Comment: A chain is a subset of $P$ such that every two elements of this subset are comparable. Chains are not elements of $P$.

Comment: I think your confusion is because of the imprecision of English language. You are reading “in” as “element of”, but in that context, “in” means “subset of”. Similar to how you can have a line in Euclidean space, despite the elements of the space all being points.

Comment: @Mark ooh so the set of all the chains in $P$ would mean the set of all the combinations of elements in $P$ that form a chain right?

Comment: @celtschk yes is it.. i would have never thought that "in" meant "subset of" in this context, thank you so much

Comment: @celtschk if you post it as an answer i will accept it as best answer

Comment: @AndreaBurgio: Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion is because of the imprecision of English language. You are reading “in” as “element of”, but in that context, “in” means “subset of”. Similar to how you can have a line in Euclidean space, despite the elements of the space all being points.